# Only one animation occurs in overridePendingTransition

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, transition

I have two activites A and B. In A, I call B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_animation_right_to_left, R.anim.activity_animation_zoom_in);
```

However, only `R.anim.activity_animation_right_to_left` works. The other animation is not applied. Also, when coming back from B to A:

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_animation_zoom_out, R.anim.activity_animation_left_to_right);
```

onl`R.anim.activity_animation_left_to_right` works. I am sure that other animation works like a charm in other situation (there is nothing wrong with them). I even use that the same transition when calling external activities such as opening a browser window. The animation works. Only for my Activity B, it doesn't work.

Edit: here is the animations XMLs:

R.anim.activity_animation_right_to_left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

R.anim.activity_animation_left_to_right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="100%" />
```

R.anim.activity_animation_zoom_in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toXScale="0.85"
        android:toYScale="0.85" />

</set>
```

Comment: A quick sanity check - swap the two animations. Is only one of them still running and which one is it? This would eliminate the function not working in your case vs. the animation resource not working.

Comment: @Delyan I have done that, and the animation resource is working. It's the parent activity that refuses to make the animation.

Comment: @A.Shatou can u post ur 4 anim xml?I want to test them.

Comment: @A. Shatou It is working.I don't know which type of effect u want but.you have to change the order of animation and  do enter animation as a zoom_in and exit animation as a activity_animation_right_to_left on first activity.and for second activity the animations r zoom_out and activity_animation_left_to_right respectively.If you want then i can post my code.?I have changed zoom_in and zoom_out in my code.

Comment: @Pratik see my comment on Ivan below

Comment: @A. Shatou k dude..may be some other issue.

Comment: @Pratik It's really weird. The animation works fine if I am starting external activity, not the one I create in the app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally fixed it. I checked my Manifest file and I found that I set the theme `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` to every activity I create. Once, I removed the theme from all of them, the animation works like a charm. Still, do not know exactly why this theme affects the animation.

Comment: More exactly, it's the item "android:windowIsTranslucent"=true in app theme that cause this bug.
Hope this help !

Answer (score 3):

Some example of animations maybe it can helps

anim_left :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

anim_right :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

anim_back_left :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

anim_back_right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

For fade in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" >
    </alpha>

</set>
```

fade_out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" >
    </alpha>

</set>
```

---

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true">
</supports-screens>
```

---

(try adding this to your manifest)

- did you try adding **overridePendingTransition** in onPause, onResume, or onCreate ?
- did you activate animations in your cellphone setting
- try other devices

Comment: I couldn't understand anything from your answer. I am not asking about how to animate. I am asking why one of the animation is not working!

Comment: Well, thanks for the examples. I don't want to set it onPause and OnResume because I have different scenarios for starting different activities. And still, I need to know why one of them is only working?

Comment: Are ou testing on emulator ? Did you try with diferent cellphones with several android versions ?

Comment: On the device only (Samsung Galaxy S3)

Comment: I appreciate your trial to answer the question. Please, read the question again and you'll find the answers to your questions.

Comment: Maybe you could provide more code, i think we lack informations. Something could block the animation

Answer (score 1):

I changed the animation zoom-in, zoom-out, and it works well in my device(Nexus 4).

A->B

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_animation_zoom_in, R.anim.activity_animation_right_to_left);
```

B->A

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_animation_left_to_right, R.anim.activity_animation_zoom_out);
```

R.anim.activity_animation_zoom_in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fromXScale="0.5"
    android:fromYScale="0.5"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

R.anim.activity_animation_zoom_out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<scale
    android:duration="300"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5" />

</set>
```

Comment: No. Only the zoom animation works for the entering activity. The existing activity has no animation whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

use startActivityForResult .. and override onActivityResult in Source Activity (Activity A ) and apply reverse animation (e.g right to left). use that below i am using

```
          @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)          {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.transition_left_to_right, R.anim.transition_left_to_right_out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you go from A to B, A goes to background and it is still alive, so when you come back from B to A, `overridePendingTransition` won't work for A. As [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) says about `overridePendingTransition`:

> Call immediately after one of the flavors of startActivity(Intent) or finish() to specify an explicit transition animation to perform next.

Could you try by put `finish` in A. just like you did in B when coming from B to A, just before `overridePendingTransition`, to make sure A is killed so `overridePendingTransition` can work, like this:

Activity A:

```
/** Called when the user presses the Next soft button */
public void nextButtonOnClick(View view) {
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_animation_right_to_left, R.anim.activity_animation_zoom_in);

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    intent.setClass(this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Activity B:

```
/** Called when the user presses the Back soft button */
public void backButtonOnClick(View view) {
        onBackPressed();
}

@Override
/** Called when the user presses the Back hard button */
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_animation_zoom_out, R.anim.activity_animation_left_to_right);

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    intent.setClass(this, ActivityA.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: But I don't want to kill Activity A. And according to the documentation as you mentioned, I don't have to (since I am already calling startActivity)