# Android overridePendingTransition shows only entry half of the Animation

Tags: android, animation, android-pendingintent, transition

I have looked through the SO answers to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284238/overridependingtransition-shows-enter-animation-only), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513262/only-one-animation-occurs-in-overridependingtransition), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365187/startactivity-overridependingtransition-only-shows-enter-animation). Those proposed solutions did not work for me. I have a test app where all of my transitions do work, so I am confident in my animation xml. Here is my Intent:

```
static private void doBundleJump( Action loadPkgAction, Context context ) 
{
    LoadPackageAction loadPackageAction = (LoadPackageAction) loadPkgAction;
    Intent intent = new Intent(((Activity)context), BundleJumpActivity.class);
    BigBergSingleton single = BigBergSingleton.getSingleton();

    if( LoadDefaultPackageAction.class.isInstance(loadPackageAction)  ) 
    {
        loadPackageAction.setPackageId( single.getDefaultPackage() );
    }

    if(single.isHasAssets() == true)
    {
        intent.putExtra("packageName","");
        intent.putExtra("bundle", "bundle/"+ loadPackageAction.getPackageId());
    }
    else
    {
        intent.putExtra("packageName",single.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("bundle", loadPackageAction.getPackageId());
    }
    intent.putExtra("startPackage",single.getDefaultPackage());
    intent.putExtra("transitionType", loadPackageAction.transitionType);
    intent.putExtra("transitionDuration", loadPackageAction.transitionDuration);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

I call overridePendingIntent(int, int) in the target's (BundleJumpActivity) on create, but I have also called it after startActivity(intent) in the doBundleJump() method above. No matter what I try, I get only the entry animation. Any thoughts on making this work correctly will be appreciated.

Comment: Been running into this issue myself. I've finally tracked it down to declaring windowIsTranslucent = true or to using Theme.NoTitleBar.Transparent inside your declared Styles. Why this occurs? I have no freakin' clue, but it's really pissing me off. Removing the transparency on the Activity allows it to animate... You haven't found a solution, have you?